# PyQt - access data of another interface?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a python script with 2 classes, each one is a different PyQt interface.

The first one is the main interface, and the second one is a "pop-up interface" - it appears when you click a button in the main interface.

Whenever that pop-up interface is launched via the main interface, i need it to display data coming from the main interface.

How can i do that if they're both in different classes?

For example, main interface:

```
class MainUI(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(QtGui.QWidget, self).__init__()

    self.myData = "data"
```

pop-up interface:

```
class PopUp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    # some stuff here
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the data into the constructor for `PopUp`

```
class PopUp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
```

If this is not feasible due to the design of your project, you can use [Signals and Slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) to pass the data between classes.

Comment: Right, can't believe i didn't think about that.. thanks!